# What is the most efficient way to compute the inverse of a general matrix using cuSolver?

Tags: matrix, cuda, gpu, cublas, cusolver

I have in mind to to use `getrf` and `getrs` from the cuSolver package and to solve `AB=X` with `B=I`.

- Is this the most best way to solve this problem?
- If so, what is the best way to create the col-major identity matrix `B` in device memory? It can be done trivially using a `for` loop but this would 1. take up a lot of memory and 2. be quite slow. Is there a faster way?

Note that cuSolver does not provide `getri` unfortunately. Therefore I must to use `getrs`.

Comment: Could you add the methods you used already to your question please? Thanks!

Comment: Certainly. I posted the question too hastily. I've added more details now. Please let me know if you require more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until CUDA provides the LAPACK API `getri`, I think `getrf` and `getrs` is the best choice for large matrix inversion.

The matrix `B` is of the same size as `A`, so I don't think allocating `B` makes this task consume much larger memory than its input/output data does.

The complexity of `getrf` and `getrs` are `O(n^3)` and `O(n^2)`, respectively, while setting `B=I` is of `O(n^2) + O(n)`.  I don't think it should be a bottleneck of the whole procedure.  You may share your implementation, so we could check where the problem could be.

Comment: I want to to point for anyone who is asking the something out that Magma does have getrf and getri. This is what I'm currently using.

Comment: The complexity of `getrs` is O(n^2 nrhs) for nrhs right-hand sides. For an inversion, you need to solve with an n x n identity matrix, so nrhs = n, thus it is O(n^3). MAGMA's `getri` exploits the structure of the identity matrix, so its complexity is a constant factor lower than using `getrs`, and MAGMA does it in-place, overwriting the matrix A.